# How to protect i18n bundle integrity in larger teams?

Tags: svn, internationalization

We use Subversion to manage our project files, including the seam managed message bundles which have the highest mutation rate of the whole project.

Ever so often a developer reads past a line during diff merge and accidentally reverts some changes, which usually slips through the testing process.

What practices have you adopted to ensure bundle integrity?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention how you find out who breaks bundle integrity. But I'm guessing you can tell. I would give these two punishments to the one who broke the build:

- Make tests to ensure that the reason for the break cannot happen again.
- Build X additional number of tests. This makes them more familar with the code as well as increases your build's testability.